# Place an image some pixels below the screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to flutter, for the tutorial screen, I have designed with a single line main text, a two-line subtext, and an image we should be positioned some pixels below from the screen bottom. In iOS, I would have placed this image with a bottom constraint of -40px. How do we achieve this in flutter? Also, the tutorial screen has paging.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, basically use a Positioned widget within a Stack widget   :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = const Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            //left: 0,
            bottom: -40,
            child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/350/550"),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              Text("Hello World!", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)),
              Text("Hello World!", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26)),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: image goes down with the size of the text , my requirement is , the image should be -40 always from bottom , the origin y of the image should not go down with the growth of the text

Comment: Try now. Made changes so that size of text does not affect the image.